# What keys do I click to go into camera perspective?

Tags: camera, shortcut

I cannot find any information on the shortcut keys to camera perspective.

Comment: Press the Zero key.

Answer (score 2):

If you forgot some shortcuts, you can always find it in menu:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just press the Numpad Zero key. It won't work if you don't press it on the numpad.